# Understanding the sencha touch object model

Tags: object, user-interface, scope, sencha-touch

Okay, so I have the following class definition:

```
MyApp.views.ItemAction = Ext.extend(Ext.ActionSheet, {
  items: [{
    text: 'cancel',
    handler: function(){
      this.hide();
    }
  }]
});
```

When I create an instance of `ItemAction` and `show()` it, an action sheet appears. Brilliant.

Now my problem: pushing the `cancel` button will **hide the button itself, and not the parent sheet.**

How do I solve this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try

```
handler: function(){
            this.up().hide();
         }
```

up will navigate up the owner chain.  Calling it without any variables will get the immediate owner.  But calling destroy is also a good idea since it will remove the sheet from the dom.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I amended my code to look like this:

```
MyApp.views.ItemAction = Ext.extend(Ext.ActionSheet, {
    id: 'itemaction',
    items: [{
        text: 'cancel',
        handler: function(){
          Ext.getCmp('itemaction').destroy();
          //do other stuff here...
        }
    }]
});
```

And it works; I will use that for now, but of course I will appreciate a less kludgy solution (and no, setting the item `scope` to `this` does not work -- I get a `DomWindow` object if I do this).

Cheers